# Extension of Leray spectral sequence, Vakil's 23.4 H

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If you have a morphism
\begin{equation}
(X,\mathscr{O}_X) \xrightarrow {\pi} (Y, \mathscr{O}_Y) 
\end{equation}
for every $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$, there is a spectral sequence with $E_2$ terms given by $H^q(Y,R^p \pi_* \mathscr{F})$ abutting to $H^{p+q}(X,\mathscr{F})$. This is the statement of Leray spectral sequence.

In Vakil's book, ex. 23.4 H is about the extension of Leray spectral sequence, for composition of morphisms
\begin{equation}
(X,\mathscr{O}_X) \xrightarrow {\pi} (Y, \mathscr{O}_Y) \xrightarrow {\rho}(Z,\mathscr{O}_Z)
\end{equation}
what is the proper generalization of Leray spectral sequence ?

I know very little about spectral sequence, and all that I have seen are with only two indices, i.e. $E_{p,q}$, how could we incorporate three indices in a spectral sequence?

Comment: Isn't this generalization just the spectral sequence for composing two direct images ? That is the spectral sequence $E_2^{p,q}=R^p\rho_*R^q\pi_*\mathcal{F}\Rightarrow R^{p+q}(\rho\circ\pi)_*\mathcal{F}$. Note that if $\rho$ is the continuous map to the one point space, you get exactly the Leray spectral sequence.